# Subsetting each 5 rows into 5 columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is rather messy, and it is all in one column. I want to be able to split the rows into columns.

The rows can be split into 5 different columns, for each 5 rows because they follow this systematic progression.

Here is an example of my dataset with the expected outcome of what It should look like:

```
x

257
CET CENTRAL ENGLAND
GB
+52:25:12
-001:49:48

#to
 x      b                   c         d           e 
257   CET CENTRAL ENGLAND   GB   +52:25:12    -001:49:48
```

Reproducible code:

```
c("257", "CET CENTRAL ENGLAND                     ", "GB", "+52:25:12", 
"-001:49:48", "  78", "271", "ARMAGH                                  ", 
"GB", "+54:21:00", "-006:39:00", "  62", "272", "ESKDALEMUIR                             ", 
"GB", "+55:19:00", "-003:12:00", " 242", "274", "RADCLIFFE METEOROLOGICAL STATION OXFORD ", 
"GB", "+51:45:40", "-001:15:50", "  63", "273", "HULL                                    ", 
"GB", "+53:45:21", "-000:21:23", "   2", "275", "WICK                                    ", 
"GB", "+58:27:00", "-003:05:00", "  36", "348", "LERWICK                                 ", 
"GB", "+60:08:00", "-001:11:00", "  82", "1627", "KIRKWALL                                ", 
"GB", "+58:57:00", "-002:54:00", "  26", "349", "STORNOWAY AIRPORT                       ", 
"GB", "+58:12:49", "-006:19:03", "  15", "350", "VALLEY                                  ", 
"GB", "+53:15:00", "-004:32:00", "  11", "351", "WADDINGTON                              ", 
"GB", "+53:09:58", "-000:31:26", "  68", "352", "CAMBORNE                                ", 
"GB", "+50:13:00", "-005:19:00", "  88", "1628", "KINLOSS                                 ", 
"GB", "+57:39:00", "-003:34:12", "   5", "1629", "CRAIBSTONE                              ", 
"GB", "+57:10:48", "-002:12:00", " 102", "1630", "MYLNEFIELD                              ", 
"GB", "+56:27:00", "-003:04:12", "  31", "1639", "CAMBRIDGE (B. GDNS)                     ", 
"GB", "+52:11:35", "+000:07:55", "  13", "1632", "ASKHAM BRYAN                            ", 
"GB", "+53:55:12", "-001:10:12", "  32", "1633", "SHAWBURY                                ", 
"GB", "+52:48:00", "-002:40:12", "  72", "1634", "GOUDHURST                               ", 
"GB", "+51:04:48", "+000:27:36", "  85", "1636", "PAISLEY                                 ", 
"GB", "+55:50:43", "-004:25:46", "  32", "1631", "RINGWAY                                 ", 
"GB", "+53:21:00", "-002:16:48", "  69", "1637", "CWMYSTWYTH                              ", 
"GB", "+52:21:00", "-003:49:12", " 301", "1635", "DALE FORT                               ", 
"GB", "+51:42:00", "-005:09:00", "  33", "1638", "LONG ASHTON                             ", 
"GB", "+51:25:48", "-002:40:12", "  51", "1640", "ALDERGROVE                              ", 
"GB", "+54:39:00", "-006:13:12", "  81", "1800", "AUCHINCRUIVE                            ", 
"GB", "+55:28:37", "-004:33:58", "  48", "1801", "GLENLEE                                 ", 
"GB", "+55:05:56", "-004:11:10", "  55", "1802", "THREAVE                                 ", 
"GB", "+54:55:30", "-003:57:00", "  73", "1803", "RONALDSWAY                              ", 
"GB", "+54:05:06", "-004:37:59", "  16", "1804", "NEWTON RIGG                             ", 
"GB", "+54:40:11", "-002:47:11", " 169", "1805", "GRIZEDALE                               ", 
"GB", "+54:20:17", "-003:01:12", "  91", "1806", "PRESTON: MOOR PARK                      ", 
"GB", "+53:46:26", "-002:42:11", "  33", "1807", "HAWARDEN BRIDGE                         ", 
"GB", "+53:13:00", "-003:01:38", "   5", "1808", "LOGGERHEADS: COLOMENDY CENTRE           ", 
"GB", "+53:09:00", "-003:11:46", " 210", "1809", "INVERNESS                               ", 
"GB", "+57:29:13", "-004:13:23", "   4", "1810", "ABERPORTH                               ", 
"GB", "+52:08:20", "-004:34:19", " 133", "1811", "GOGERDDAN                               ", 
"GB", "+52:25:55", "-004:01:12", "  31", "1812", "YEOVILTON                               ", 
"GB", "+51:00:22", "-002:38:24", "  20", "1813", "SWANAGE                                 ", 
"GB", "+50:36:50", "-001:57:29", "  10", "1814", "PLYMOUTH: MOUNTBATTEN                   ", 
"GB", "+50:21:14", "-004:07:16", "  50", "1815", "SLAPTON                                 ", 
"GB", "+50:17:31", "-003:39:04", "  32", "1816", "ST MAWGAN                               ", 
"GB", "+50:26:13", "-004:59:56", " 103", "1817", "BUDE                                    ", 
"GB", "+50:49:41", "-004:32:46", "  15", "1818", "BRAEMAR                                 ", 
"GB", "+57:00:22", "-003:23:49", " 339", "1819", "BALMORAL                                ", 
"GB", "+57:02:13", "-003:13:12", " 283", "1820", "HILLSBOROUGH                            ", 
"GB", "+54:27:07", "-006:04:12", " 116", "1821", "STORMONT CASTLE                         ", 
"GB", "+54:36:11", "-005:49:44", "  56", "1822", "LOUGH NAVAR FOREST                      ", 
"GB", "+54:26:20", "-007:54:11", " 126", "1823", "GUERNSEY: AIRPORT                       ", 
"GB", "+49:25:59", "-002:36:00", " 101", "1824", "JERSEY: AIRPORT                         ", 
"GB", "+49:13:01", "-002:12:00", "  84", "1825", "DYCE                                    ", 
"GB", "+57:12:18", "-002:12:14", "  65", "1826", "ALWEN                                   ", 
"GB", "+53:03:40", "-003:33:14", " 345", "1827", "TIREE                                   ", 
"GB", "+56:29:49", "-006:53:13", "   9", "1828", "ARDTALNAIG                              ", 
"GB", "+56:31:44", "-004:06:40", " 130", "1829", "FASKALLY                                ", 
"GB", "+56:43:05", "-003:46:08", "  94", "1830", "LEUCHARS                                ", 
"GB", "+56:22:37", "-002:51:43", "  10", "1831", "PENICUIK                                ", 
"GB", "+55:49:26", "-003:13:34", " 185", "1832", "EDINBURGH: ROYAL BOTANIC GARDEN         ", 
"GB", "+55:58:01", "-003:12:36", "  26", "1833", "DUNBAR                                  ", 
"GB", "+56:00:14", "-002:31:34", "  23", "1834", "BLYTH BRIDGE                            ", 
"GB", "+55:42:11", "-003:22:01", " 253", "1835", "BOWHILL                                 ", 
"GB", "+55:32:28", "-002:54:18", " 168", "1836", "KIELDER CASTLE                          ", 
"GB", "+55:14:02", "-002:34:44", " 201", "1837", "MORPETH: COCKLE PARK                    ", 
"GB", "+55:12:54", "-001:41:10", "  95", "1838", "HIGH MOWTHORPE                          ", 
"GB", "+54:06:18", "-000:38:31", " 175", "1839", "SKEGNESS                                ", 
"GB", "+53:08:51", "+000:20:52", "   6", "1840", "TERRINGTON ST CLEMENT                   ", 
"GB", "+52:44:42", "+000:17:24", "   2", "1841", "EAST BERGHOLT                           ", 
"GB", "+51:57:32", "+001:01:37", "   7", "1842", "WATTISHAM                               ", 
"GB", "+52:07:23", "+000:57:43", "  89", "1843", "LOWESTOFT                               ", 
"GB", "+52:29:22", "+001:44:46", "  25", "1844", "ROTHAMSTED                              ", 
"GB", "+51:48:22", "-000:21:30", " 128", "1845", "WRITTLE                                 ", 
"GB", "+51:43:55", "+000:25:52", "  32", "1846", "MALHAM TARN                             ", 
"GB", "+54:06:00", "-002:09:43", " 381", "1847", "BRADFORD                                ", 
"GB", "+53:48:48", "-001:46:20", " 134", "1848", "SHEFFIELD                               ", 
"GB", "+53:22:51", "-001:29:23", " 131", "1849", "BUXTON                                  ", 
"GB", "+53:15:27", "-001:54:44", " 307", "1850", "NOTTINGHAM: WATNALL                     ", 
"GB", "+53:00:18", "-001:15:00", " 117", "1851", "WARSOP                                  ", 
"GB", "+53:13:23", "-001:06:54", "  46", "1852", "NEWTOWN LINFORD                         ", 
"GB", "+52:40:48", "-001:12:58", " 119", "1853", "WELLESBOURNE                            ", 
"GB", "+52:12:22", "-001:36:11", "  47", "1854", "KEELE                                   ", 
"GB", "+52:59:53", "-002:16:12", " 179", "1855", "MALVERN                                 ", 
"GB", "+52:06:45", "-002:18:25", "  62", "1856", "HALESOWEN                               ", 
"GB", "+52:26:13", "-002:04:30", " 153", "1857", "KINLOCHEWE                              ", 
"GB", "+57:36:47", "-005:18:36", "  25", "1858", "LYONSHALL                               ", 
"GB", "+52:12:43", "-002:58:05", " 155", "1859", "HAMPSTEAD                               ", 
"GB", "+51:33:40", "-000:10:44", " 137", "1860", "HEATHROW                                ", 
"GB", "+51:28:44", "-000:26:56", "  25", "1861", "WYE                                     ", 
"GB", "+51:11:06", "+000:56:53", "  56", "1862", "MANSTON                                 ", 
"GB", "+51:20:46", "+001:20:24", "  49", "1863", "BOGNOR REGIS                            ", 
"GB", "+50:46:52", "-000:40:34", "   7", "1864", "EASTBOURNE                              ", 
"GB", "+50:45:42", "+000:17:07", "   7", "1865", "HASTINGS                                ", 
"GB", "+50:51:18", "+000:34:19", "  45", "1866", "WALLINGFORD                             ", 
"GB", "+51:36:11", "-001:06:29", "  48", "1867", "HURN                                    ", 
"GB", "+50:46:44", "-001:50:02", "  10", "1868", "EVERTON                                 ", 
"GB", "+50:44:31", "-001:34:26", "  16", "1869", "LECKFORD                                ", 
"GB", "+51:07:23", "-001:26:17", " 117", "1870", "HAYLING ISLAND                          ", 
"GB", "+50:47:02", "-000:59:02", "   4", "1871", "ALICE HOLT LODGE                        ", 
"GB", "+51:10:37", "-000:50:53", " 115", "1872", "LYNEHAM                                 ", 
"GB", "+51:30:07", "-001:59:28", " 145", "1873", "RHUM: KINLOCH                           ", 
"GB", "+57:00:50", "-006:17:13", "   5", "1874", "BENMORE: YOUNGER BOTANIC GARDEN         ", 
"GB", "+56:01:41", "-004:59:10", "  12", "1875", "BUTE: ROTHESAY                          ", 
"GB", "+55:50:20", "-005:03:50", "  43", "1876", "LEADHILLS                               ", 
"GB", "+55:25:01", "-003:45:32", " 393", "1877", "CARNWATH                                ", 
"GB", "+55:42:00", "-003:37:59", " 208", "3507", "BRAEMAR-1                               ", 
"GB", "+57:00:40", "-003:23:46", " 327", "3508", "LOWESTOFT MONKTON AVENUE                ", 
"GB", "+52:28:59", "+001:43:52", "  18", "427", "STORNOWAY                               ", 
"GB", "+58:13:12", "-006:19:12", "  21", "3872", "HUNTINGTON                              ", 
"GB", "+52:22:00", "+000:13:00", "  49", "2124", "BRIZE NORTON                            ", 
"GB", "+51:45:00", "-001:34:48", "  88", "3875", "UPPER HEYFORD                           ", 
"GB", "+51:55:59", "-001:15:00", " 134", "3876", "FAIRFORD                                ", 
"GB", "+51:40:59", "-001:46:59", "  87", "3877", "GREENHAM                                ", 
"GB", "+51:22:59", "-001:16:59", " 122", "3880", "LAKENHEATH RAF                          ", 
"GB", "+52:24:00", "+000:34:00", "  10", "3881", "MARHAM                                  ", 
"GB", "+52:39:00", "+000:33:00", "  23", "3882", "SCULTHORPE                              ", 
"GB", "+52:51:00", "+000:46:00", "  65", "3884", "BENTWATERS                              ", 
"GB", "+52:07:59", "+001:25:59", "  26", "3886", "WETHERSFIELD                            ", 
"GB", "+51:58:00", "+000:30:00", "  98", "3887", "WOODBRIDGE                              ", 
"GB", "+52:04:59", "+001:24:00", "  29", "11102", "BLACKPOOL SQUIRES GATE                  ", 
"GB", "+53:46:27", "-003:02:17", "  10", "2127", "BOSCOMBE DOWN                           ", 
"GB", "+51:09:41", "-001:45:11", " 126", "2115", "CARLISLE                                ", 
"GB", "+54:56:03", "-002:57:44", "  28", "11103", "CAWOOD                                  ", 
"GB", "+53:49:39", "-001:08:48", "   6", "11104", "CRANWELL                                ", 
"GB", "+53:01:51", "-000:30:07", "  63", "461", "DURHAM                                  ", 
"GB", "+54:46:04", "-001:35:04", " 102", "11105", "LACOCK                                  ", 
"GB", "+51:25:51", "-002:06:48", "  49", "11106", "LOSSIEMOUTH                             ", 
"GB", "+57:42:42", "-003:19:19", "   7", "11107", "MONKS WOOD                              ", 
"GB", "+52:24:04", "-000:14:07", "  41", "11108", "MORECAMBE NO 2                          ", 
"GB", "+54:04:34", "-002:51:30", "   7", "11109", "PERSHORE COLLEGE                        ", 
"GB", "+52:05:59", "-002:03:31", "  37", "11110", "SUTTON BONINGTON                        ", 
"GB", "+52:50:10", "-001:14:59", "  43", "11111", "WIGHT ST CATHERINES POINT               ", 
"GB", "+50:34:30", "-001:17:44", "  20", "11112", "WISLEY                                  ", 
"GB", "+51:18:36", "-000:28:29", "  38", "11113", "WOBURN                                  ", 
"GB", "+52:00:51", "-000:35:40", "  89")
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

Note: Actually your data has 6 columns.

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(v, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE))
head(d)
#>    X1                                       X2 X3        X4         X5   X6
#> 1 257 CET CENTRAL ENGLAND                      GB +52:25:12 -001:49:48   78
#> 2 271 ARMAGH                                   GB +54:21:00 -006:39:00   62
#> 3 272 ESKDALEMUIR                              GB +55:19:00 -003:12:00  242
#> 4 274 RADCLIFFE METEOROLOGICAL STATION OXFORD  GB +51:45:40 -001:15:50   63
#> 5 273 HULL                                     GB +53:45:21 -000:21:23    2
#> 6 275 WICK                                     GB +58:27:00 -003:05:00   36
```